# Comparing each element in Series to every other - Is there a better way than nesting .apply()?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Series of varying length n with which I would like to achieve the following:

```
for each element in the series:
 compare element to all elements in series
 save result of comparison
```

This should result in a DataFrame with (n * n) comparison results. Half of these will be redundant duplicates so the actual expected result will be half of this dataframe with size n * n / 2.

Currently I have achieved this by nesting two .apply() functions like so:

```
data = *pandas Series containing strings*

result['data'] = data
result['calculation'] = data.apply(lambda x: f(data, x))

def f(x, y):
    ret = []
    ret = x.apply(lambda x: comparison(x, y)) # comparison is in this case 'from Levenshtein import ratio'
    ret = ret.tolist()
    return ret
```

This gives the DataFrame 'result' with result['data'] as the original Series of strings and result['calculation'] as a Series containing lists of len = n with each calculation value.

**So this works but 1) it calculates also the redundant bottom half of the result matrix and 2) it is in any case time consuming for larger data sets. Is there a better way of doing this?**

**EDIT:**
I should have specified that I ruled out using nested for-loops for performance reasons. I assumed that for-loops must be less efficient than using built in pandas functionality such as apply (or whatever better solution that I'm still unaware of).
This also turns out to be the case: For n = 1000 the results are `apply Wall time: 5.72 s` and `for-loops Wall time: 5min 35s`

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your for loops so that the inner loop skips the items that were already compared.
First, create a dataframe to store the results (assume that your original dataframe is called 'data'):

```
results=pd.DataFrame(index=data.index,columns=data.index)
```

Then apply a nested for loop:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(data)):
        # do something
        results.iloc[i,j]=...#store the result
```

For example, if your data looks like: `data=pd.Series([1,25,6,7],index=['a','b','c','d'])` and you let `results.iloc[i,j]=data[i]+data[j]`, you will have `results` as a half-filled n*n dataframe:

```
     a    b    c    d
a  NaN   26    7    8
b  NaN  NaN   31   32
c  NaN  NaN  NaN   13
d  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: I should have specified in the question that I ruled out using nested for-loops for performance reasons. I assumed that for-loops must be less efficient than using built in pandas functionality such as .apply(). I will update this in the question. Thanks for the response though!

Comment: I am not sure about that: to my knowledge, some pandas built-in for pair-wise test (such as df.corr) do use a similar nested loop structure. [libalgos-pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/algos.pyx).  If you have doubt, why not timeit yourself? Based on personal experience apply is not neccesarily so fast, especially when you have it conjugated.....

Comment: I wrote the for-loop implementation and it turns out that the conjugated apply's are orders of magnitude faster. For n = 1000 the results are `apply Wall time: 5.72 s` and `for-loops Wall time: 5min 35s`